# rampUser method is getting stuck in gatling 3.3

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am having issues using `rampUser()` method in my gatling script. The request is getting stuck after the following entry which had passed half way through.

**Version : 3.3**

```
================================================================================
2019-12-18 09:51:44                                          45s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=2      KO=0     )
> graphql / request_0                                      (OK=1      KO=0     )
> rest / request_0                                         (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- xxxSimulation ---------------------------------------------------
[#####################################                                     ] 50%
          waiting: 1      / active: 0      / done: 1     
================================================================================
```

I am seeing the following in the log which gets repeated for ever and the log size increases

```
09:35:46.495 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload - Injecting 0 users in scenario xxSimulation, continue=true
09:35:47.494 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] DEBUG io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenWorkload - Injecting 0 users in scenario xxSimulation, continue=true
```

The above issue is happening only with `rampUser` and not happening with

```
atOnceUsers()
rampUsersPerSec()
rampConcurrentUsers()
constantConcurrentUsers()
constantUsersPerSec()
incrementUsersPerSec()
```

Is there a way to mimic `rampUser()` in some other way or is there a solution for this.
My code is very minimal

```
setUp(
    scenarioBuilder.inject(
      rampUsers(2).during(1 minutes)
    )
  ).protocols(protocolBuilder)
```

I am stuck with this for some time and my earlier post with more information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295429/injecting-0-users-in-scenario-message-during-rampup-users-in-gatling)

Can any of the gatling experts help me on this?

Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have slightly incorrect syntax for a `rampUsers`. You should try remove a `.` before `during`.
I have in my own script this code and it works fine:

```scala
setUp(userScenario.inject(
    //  atOnceUsers(4),
        rampUsers(24) during (1 seconds))
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Also, in Gatling documentation example is also without a dot [Open model](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup#open-model):

```scala
  scn.inject(
    nothingFor(4 seconds), // 1
    atOnceUsers(10), // 2
    rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds), // HERE
    constantUsersPerSec(20) during (15 seconds), // 4
    constantUsersPerSec(20) during (15 seconds) randomized, // 5
    rampUsersPerSec(10) to 20 during (10 minutes), // 6
    rampUsersPerSec(10) to 20 during (10 minutes) randomized, // 7
    heavisideUsers(1000) during (20 seconds) // 8
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
)
```

My guess is that syntax can't be parsed, so instead 0 is substituted. (Here is example of rounding. Not applicable, but as reference: [gatling-user-injection-constantuserspersec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355372/gatling-user-injection-constantuserspersec))

Also, you mentioned that others method work, could you paste working code as well?